# firefox not storing $window.sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firefox, session-storage

I have firefox 38.0 beta version. everything was working fine. yesterday i updated it standard release which was 37.0.1. Now in my application i am using the following code.

```
$window.sessionStorage.setItem("LoggedInUser", JSON.stringify(data));
```

it is giving me error that *`Error: The operation is insecure.`* i am using angularjs. if i surround it with try catch then the error is gone but var not set in sessionStorage. i debugged it and noticed that sessionStorage is undefined. Anyone can guide me? i tried reverting back to beta version but still same issue. I am using firebug to see the session storage. i also installed FireStoragePlus plugin to watch sessionStorage variables.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpw2hf7h/) added.

[image with error](http://postimg.org/image/kymd31j31/) added.

Comment: $window is the angular one not jquery one. details are here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window

Comment: Oh my bad… But still, it does work on mac version of 38.0 beta

Comment: @Kaiido: it should the same as the ordinary `window` global, if the docs are correct.

Comment: It also does work for me on virtual Win7 http://jsfiddle.net/xpw2hf7h/2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [firefox 13.0 cross domain localStorage access: Error: The operation is insecure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929337/firefox-13-0-cross-domain-localstorage-access-error-the-operation-is-insecure)